# Why am i getting problem3.c:20:23: error: expected expression before ‘int’?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Ive been over the code a few times and cant seem to find the problem. Ive seen some other people with similar error and some of them involve casting issues, but im having trouble seeing why that might be an issue here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>

int *getData(FILE *fp, int *length);
int **getGroups(int *mainArray, int num, int remainder);

int main(void)
{
   FILE *fp;
   int *mainArray, length, num, remainder, **groups;
   double sq;
   fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
   mainArray=getData(fp, &length);
   sq = (sqrt(length));
   num = (int)sq;
   remainder = length - (num*num);
   groups = getGroups(int *mainArray, int num, int remainder);

   return(0);
}
```

the file size in question is 100 ints, so the square root should be 10. ive checked this in earlier iterations of the code and num does = 10.  Ill leave out the actual functions to keep this from being too long and since the error is long before them. Ill include all the relevant errors the compiler gives though...

```
problem3.c: In function ‘main’:
problem3.c:19:23: error: expected expression before ‘int’
problem3.c:19:23: error: too few arguments to function ‘getGroups’
problem3.c:7:7: note: declared here
```

im pretty thrown off by the too few arguements to function getGroups since its pretty obvious that theres 3 arguements every place i use it. Im assuming this error is somehow caused by the first?

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
groups = getGroups(int *mainArray, int num, int remainder);
```

is not valid syntax, that's basically a copy of the prototype, not a proper call.

It should be:

```
groups = getGroups(mainArray, num, remainder);
```

Comment: lol. thats what lack of sleep does to you. didnt understand the error because ive never been that dumb. thanks ^_^